# Vue - Firebase Auth Get Data

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, crud

After I've login with firebase auth (email/password), how do I get data from firebase?

My code right now.

Once you login you're redirected to a blogs page. In that blogs page there is a GET call to firebase to get the data. Right now I'm getting a permission denied error. Do I have to send some kind of auth token with the GET request?

Login.vue

```
<script>
  import firebase from 'firebase'

  export default {
    name: 'login',
    data() {
      return {
        email: '',
        password: '',
      }
    },
    methods: {
      login() {
        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.email, this.password)
          .then(
            user => {
              this.$router.replace('blogs')
            },
            error => console.log(error)
          )
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Blogs.vue

```
<script>
  import firebase from 'firebase'

  export default {
    name: 'blogs',
    data() {
      return {
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.$http.get('data.json')
        .then(
          posts => console.log(posts)
        )
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `this.$http.get('data.json')` doesn't look like a Firebase database call, am I missing something?

Comment: it uses vue-resource and i've also set up a default `Vue.http.options.root = 'https://something-98765.firebaseio.com/'`